# Asp Core Razor Pages: Access property of ViewComponent

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a ViewComponent which creates an renders a select box. The value selected is available on the public property "GewaehltesJahr" of the ViewComponent.

The ViewComponent is embedded like shown below into my main page:

```
 <vc:jahresauswahl startjahr=2021/>
```

My problem is:
**How can I access the property "GewaehltesJahr" of the ViewComponent from my main page?**

Comment: What do you mean for `access the property "GewaehltesJahr" of the ViewComponent from my main page`? It seems your view component contains a select box which represents the value of `GewaehltesJahr`. When you use the `<vc:jahresauswahl startjahr=2021/>`, it can render the select box successfully in your main page. So i don't understand what do you mean for access in main page. Also you can pass the selected value and receive the value for `GewaehltesJahr` property in backend.

Comment: Did you do not render the select box with the `GewaehltesJahr` property? Or did you do not receive the value for `GewaehltesJahr` property in backend when you did some operation like submit form in your main page? Please share more details and more code. What is your `GewaehltesJahr` property? Does it in a model? Pls also share with use.

Comment: I am trying to use der ViewComponent like the UserControls in formerly asp-versions.
Inside of the ViewComponent there is a html-select. The names and number of options in that select get´s automatically created based on the "startjahr"-parameter in the constructor of the ViewComponent. That works fine. If i use the ViewComponent inside of my main page the select is displayed properly. But in my main page I need to now, which value is currently selected in the select inside of the ViewComponent.
Structure:
->main page
 --> ViewComponent
  ---> HTML-Select

Comment: So you want to set the selectlist selected when you render the view component? pls share enough code.